# Preview CURL request prior to sending it

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl

I am sending an XML SOAP request via CURL in PHP.

Is there a way of viewing (print_r/var_dump) the entire request including headers before sending it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`. But I don't think you will be able to get anything from it until the request has been completed.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

See the PHP [manual page for `curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for the options.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `curl_setopt($request, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);` and then after `curl_exec($request);` see the request sent with `echo curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)`. But it only works AFTER the request is sent. I don't think it's possible to get what is going to be sent before actually executing it.